# Bubble sort not sorting properly in python

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I'm making bubble sort in Python but have no idea why it doesn't sort properly.

```
N = [80000, 20, 40 , 50, 10000, 50, 60, 90, 100, 5000, 22]
for i in range(len(N)-1):
    for j in range(len(N)-i-1):
        if(N[i] > N[i+1]):
            N[i], N[i+1] = N[i+1], N[i]
print(N)
```

This is result of this code

```
[20, 40, 50, 10000, 50, 60, 90, 100, 5000, 22, 80000]
```

Comment: You should use `j` and `j+1` as the indices, not `i` and `i+1`.

Comment: Hint: you're not using j as an index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compare `N[j]` with `N[j+1]`, because you need repeatedly *swapping* the *adjacent* `elements` if they are in wrong order.

```
N = [80000, 20, 40 , 50, 10000, 50, 60, 90, 100, 5000, 22]
for i in range(len(N)-1):
    for j in range(len(N)-i-1):
        if(N[j] > N[j+1]):
            N[j], N[j+1] = N[j+1], N[j]
print(N)
```

Output

```
[20, 22, 40, 50, 50, 60, 90, 100, 5000, 10000, 80000]
```

Comment: I watched my code several times but didn't notice I misread i and j.. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should use 'j' instead of 'i' in the body of the second loop. Otherwise it is pointless to have both loops. Only the outer loop is effectively executed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you mixed up your indices i and j. It should read:

```
N = [80000, 20, 40 , 50, 10000, 50, 60, 90, 100, 5000, 22]
for i in range(len(N)-1):
for j in range(len(N)-i-1):
    if(N[j] > N[j+1]):
        N[j], N[j+1] = N[j+1], N[j]
print(N)
```

Output:

```
[20, 22, 40, 50, 50, 60, 90, 100, 5000, 10000, 80000]
```